# Trigger an update in a Feed after posting a reaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getstream-io

I'm working with the reactions of activities using `getstream.io` and Reactjs without using
javascript for my custom components instead of the components they provide.

I want to refresh the activity from the feed so I can get updated reactions such as comments in real time for every client watching the activity.

I have a structure like:

```
Feed having N activities.

Checking activity type to display a component <SharedStuff><ActivityTypeDisplay /></SharedStuff>
```

Where `<SharedStuff>` contains the comment handling.
I'm able to add a comment and display it instantly where I want using `setState(newComment)`
but it's not the desired behaviour.

Is there a way to trigger an update for the activity in the feed ? because I'm passing the activity info as props to not call the api multiple times in a feed.

Desired behaviour:

```
1.- Someone scrolling the feed.

2.- Someone comments an activity.

3.- The Feed updates the activity.

4.- Every Feed that has that activity now has the updated comments in realtime.
```

Comment: In case someone need it, I had to manually refresh the activity. Here's what I did:

1.- React in an activity.
2.- Grab that ID to retrieve only that activity again
3.- Find the activity in the array I used for activities
4.- Replaced old Activity data with new.
5.- The virtual dom updated itself

Comment: So what happens if the reaction is from different user on different device. You don't watch for those?

Comment: @Muteshi I ended up refactoring the code, I haven't seen the code in a year but probably I could check if you need an answer.